# Not able to change Spring Actuator Port

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

My application Is running on port 8444 but I want my actuator metrics to be exposed to a different port, by default I can access them via https://localhost:8444/actuator/health but I want them on a different port like 8086

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#production-ready-customizing-management-server-port

I followed this document and added management.server.port=8086 in my application.yml but it's just showing that site can't be reached

I tried other properties such as changing the endpoint base-path and that seems to be working fine.

I am using Spring boot 2.2.4.RELEASE and Wildfly 18,
Here is my application.yml

```
server:
  port: 8443
  servlet:
    context-path: /appName

info:
  app:
    name: name
    description: description
    version: 1.0

management.endpoints.web.exposure.include: ["health", "info", "prometheus"]
management.endpoint.health.show-details: always

spring:
  servlet:
    multipart:
      max-request-size: 100MB
  datasource:
    jndi-name: java:/datasource
  main:
    allow-bean-definition-overriding: true
management:
  server:
    port: 8086
  endpoints:
    web:
      base-path: /manage
```

Comment: can you put your application,properties snippet

Comment: Wilffly which means you are deploying your application instead of using an embedded container. As such the `server.*` properties don't take effect as Spring Boot cannot control an external application server.

Comment: @M.Deinum so what can be the work around for this ?

Comment: There isn't. You could configure WildFly to expose both ports but that would mean your whole application is accessible on both ports. Externally you simply don't have that level of control.

Comment: @M.Deinum if I do make my application accessible by an extra port any way I can configure actuator metrics to be available on that other port instead of both?

Comment: You might be able to do that with Spring Security but not in your wildfly configuration.